# Object-based classification issues on ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, image-classification

I am currently building a predictive wetland layer using Sentinnel-2 bands (RGB and Infrared), and several LiDAR derived datasets. I made a 8 band composite and have been training the model using the Random Tree Algorithm on ArcGIS Pro. I have had success making the layer using pixel-based classification and then performing a majority filter to remove noise. Overall, the product looks good, but I want to try out object-based classification.

I used the Segmentation Mean Shift tool on ArcGIS Pro and every time the output is essentially a homogenous image. Easy to identify things like lakes aren't segmented.

I have a feeling it is something to do with the input being 8 bands and the output being 3.

Am I approaching this wrong?

I could try segmenting the sentinnel-2 images first and then making a composite with the LiDAR dataset.

I am just trying to compare object-based classification to my pixel-based classification model.

Comment: The tool only uses 3 input bands, see the Band Indexes parameter in the [doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/segment-mean-shift.htm).  You could try condensing to the first three principle components https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/principal-components.htm